# Querying a large amount of files from SSH with a list of path

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I have a list of path(.txt) which is the path to SSH the data from database 
Example :

```
/home/data3/bb/00/01/01/01/2001-abc.xml
```

and I need to get all these files to my local machine
the server is running in linux, and I used to get the files from SSH client.

Since all the files are base on some parent file like /bb/...., so I used to download the whole thing.

But this time the common file is too big to download, and the xml I needed are only some of them inside the huge server.

Does anyone has ideas how to get those files? Is there any SSH library in Java so I can read the content of xml directly in JAVA? or anyway to read the list of path and only download the files I want?

Those files are usually like:

```
/home/data3/bb/00/01/01/01/200142123-abc.xml
/home/data3/bb/00/01/02/01/200123423-fseaf.xml
/home/data3/bb/03/03/01/01/200112312-fefe.xml
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what you're trying to achieve.  Are you trying to manually synchronise the content of a server directory structure to your workstation?  If that's the case, have a look at **rsync**.

Comment: It is not like synchromise.... I dont have any files on my workstation. I only have a list of path which tell me where are those files on the server. And since I have too many those paths, I am not sure if I can use any method to download all the content to my workstation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `rsync` utility.  This is especially helpful if the local machine already has many of the files, in which case `rsync` would not transfer them.

Rsync also can compress files.  It might be this easy for you:

```
rsync -azvr  source_host:/home/data3/bb/ /home/data3/bb/
```